# Require password/keycode to delete entries

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently built a corporate phone directory in Rails. I want it accessible to all staff members, but when someone clicks "Delete", I want a separate window to appear requiring a pre-set password or keycode. (That password would be set maybe in a static file in the app (like app/keys). I don't want just anyone to be able to delete entries. After that password/keycode is entered, then the app should remove the entry. Any tips on how I could do this in Rails? If this is possible, I might want to also do this for "update" on entries as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are users logged in? Why not just mark certain users as admins and then hide/show and allow/disallow those actions that way?

### *Update 1*

So since you don't have users logged in and such you can sort of hack this in pretty easily by just using HTTP Basic Authentication. See [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication), the gist is:

```
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [ :delete, :other_action, :etc ]

protected

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    username == "something" && password == "secret"
  end
end
```

It might be tricky with an ajax action... give it a try.

Comment: For now not having people login (my users have low tolerance for additional accounts or logins).  I was considering installing devise with ldap later, but might do that now if that's the only way to handle this.  Any tips for hiding the delete/edit links for non-admins if I used devise?